# How to increase DWUs on Azure Synapse Dedicated SQL Pool

Tags: azure-synapse

I inherited an Azure Dedicated SQL Pool at my current firm. The DWU was set at 100, is there a way to increase the DWU's? It would be appear I would have to create a new Dedicated SQL Pool to increaase the DWU's

[image]

Also, is there a guide showing what DWU's are best for a particular environments? For example, Microsoft recommend a minimum of 1100 DWUs for production, but I'm not sure what production environment that is based on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In Azure portal, Click the dedicated SQL resource where you need to increase DWUs.

[image]

- Then click **Scale**

[image]

- Then, Increase the DWU based on the requirement.

[image]

You can also use t-sql command, powershell to change DWUs.

**Reference:**  [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/what-is-a-data-warehouse-unit-dwu-cdwu#change-data-warehouse-units)  on Changing DWUs

Comment: Hi @Aswin, thanks for reaching out. I just realised that the Dedicated SQL pools need to be online to configure workload management ... duh! Thanks anyway